# Getting the boundaries for GPS locations, having a central GPS location and radius

Tags: differential-geometry

Let's say I have a position [image] and a radius [image: <code>r</code>]. I want to have some boundaries which by those I could evaluate any position like [image]
and determine that if [image] is in range of [image] by [image] radius or not, how can I do this?

Comment: Which software are you using? How accurate do you need the calculation to be?

Comment: @FSimardGIS i am writing my own software; `-10feet` accuracy will be OK i quess